# Filter query based on results of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query as part of a stored procedure.  It returns some metrics about a country and how many locations we have in each country.  This query works fine.

However, this returns data for all countries, including those where we have no location.  I'd like to modify it so that it only returns records where the CenterCount > 0, but the CenterCount is just an alias for the results of a subquery, so I can't just put `WHERE CenterCount > 0`.

I know I could do this by replicating that subquery either in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, but I don't want to have that subquery in there twice.  Is there a better way of doing it?

```
  SELECT 
    cn.Code as CountryCode,
    cn.CountryName,
    ( 
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CenterID))
      FROM Center.Center center
      JOIN Organization.OrganizationAddress orgAddr
      ON center.OrganizationID = orgAddr.OrganizationID
      JOIN Common.Address ca
      ON orgAddr.AddressID = ca.AddressID
      AND ca.AddressTypeID = 1 --Physical
      WHERE ca.CountryID = cn.CountryID
      AND center.ActiveInd = 1 
      AND ( (center.CenterStatusTypeID = 1) OR (center.CenterStatusTypeID = 2 AND center.OpenUTCDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETUTCDATE())) )
      AND ca.ActiveInd = 1
    ) as CenterCount,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SatelliteID))
      FROM Center.Satellite sat
      JOIN Common.Address ca
      ON sat.AddressID = ca.AddressID
      WHERE ca.CountryID = cn.CountryID
      AND sat.ActiveInd = 1
      AND sat.StatusTypeID = 2 --Approved
      AND sat.PayerTypeID = 2 --Retail
      AND sat.WebsitePresenceFlag = 1
      AND sat.OpenUTCDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETUTCDATE())      
    ) as SatelliteCount
  FROM Core.Country cn
  WHERE (@Country IS NULL OR cn.CountryID = @CountryID)
  ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: create a 'variable' and store the result of the 'CenterCount' and use that variable !

Comment: Move the subquery to be part of your main query. That way you can use the full power of SQL and do not duplicate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to just turn your original query into a common table expression, which would then allow you to use `WHERE CenterCount > 0` just like you want.

```
  ;WITH cte AS
  (
  SELECT 
    cn.Code as CountryCode,
    cn.CountryName,
    ( 
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CenterID))
      FROM Center.Center center
      JOIN Organization.OrganizationAddress orgAddr
      ON center.OrganizationID = orgAddr.OrganizationID
      JOIN Common.Address ca
      ON orgAddr.AddressID = ca.AddressID
      AND ca.AddressTypeID = 1 --Physical
      WHERE ca.CountryID = cn.CountryID
      AND center.ActiveInd = 1 
      AND ( (center.CenterStatusTypeID = 1) OR (center.CenterStatusTypeID = 2 AND center.OpenUTCDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETUTCDATE())) )
      AND ca.ActiveInd = 1
    ) as CenterCount,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SatelliteID))
      FROM Center.Satellite sat
      JOIN Common.Address ca
      ON sat.AddressID = ca.AddressID
      WHERE ca.CountryID = cn.CountryID
      AND sat.ActiveInd = 1
      AND sat.StatusTypeID = 2 --Approved
      AND sat.PayerTypeID = 2 --Retail
      AND sat.WebsitePresenceFlag = 1
      AND sat.OpenUTCDate <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETUTCDATE())      
    ) as SatelliteCount
  FROM Core.Country cn
  WHERE (@Country IS NULL OR cn.CountryID = @CountryID)
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE CenterCount > 0
  ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Great answer!  This would solve the problem.  It's SQL Server specific of course, but that's OK for me.